# Generating code (including strings and derived identifiers) from the name of a struct and the names and types of its members

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

In the context of a library I am using, creating a type such as

```cpp
struct my_name_t {
  int aaa;
  double bbb;
};
```

requires that the user also define and invoke

```cpp
HF::CompoundType create_my_name_type() {
  return {{"aaa", HF::AtomicType<int>{}},
          {"bbb", HF::AtomicType<double>{}}};
}

HIGHFIVE_REGISTER_TYPE(my_name_t, create_my_name_type)
```

The second block is 100% boilerplate: every single character in the second block is a pure function of the contents of the first block. The only things that can vary are

- the name of the struct,
- the types and names of its members.

Everything else is fully-specified by this information.

What C++ metaprogramming techniques might be used to

- generate the second block from the first, or
- generate both from some common specification?

Answer (score 0):

In the current C++ standard (C++20) there is no support for reflection, meaning, it is impossible to obtain a list of names and types of members.

(There were some discussions about adding "static reflection" to C++23 but not sure if this is still up-to-date.)

In praxis you can either write this redundant code or, if you are talking about many classes, typically generate it from some DSL (Domain Specific Language):

```
// file: X.struct

type X {
  x: int
  y: std::string
}
```

```cpp
// file: X.generated.hpp

struct X {
  int x;
  std::string y;
};

// file: X.generated.cpp

static MyCustomReflectionType info()
{
    return {
      { "x", "int" },
      { "y", "std::string" },
    };
}

REGISTER_TYPE(X, info);
```

If you need to add custom methods, you would typically generate the base class and the implement the derived class yourself.

There are also some hybrid code/generation things you can do, where you can try to extract that info from C++ code, but you'll probably shoot yourself in the foot with that.

Comment: There are tricks to discover the number and types of members, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html

Comment: DSL might be done by.. MACRO. Most reflexive library use some MACRO (as [`BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html))